# MySQL, Count values in every fields in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 32 fields that comprise of products.  The possible values in each field is H, M and L.

Mock up of my table structure

```
Product 1   Product 2   Product 3   Product 4   Product 5   ...
H           M           M           L           L           ...     
H           H           M           L           L           ...     
H           H           H           H           L           ...     
M           M           M           L           H           ...     
H           M           M           L           L           ...
```

I know I can do

```
SELECT COUNT(product_1) AS product_1_count FROM products WHERE product_1 = H

SELECT COUNT(product_1) AS product_1_count FROM products WHERE product_1 = L
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(product_1) AS product_1_count FROM products WHERE product_1 = L
```

I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this since I got 32 products.  Can you do it in 1 SQL statement or at least 3 SQL statements instead of individually selecting every product.

Comment: On first glance this looks like a bad data model. You may want to add a request on this in order to get advice. Another data model would probably make writing queries much, much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have separate columns for each product? product_1, product_2 and so on?

You could at least group by product:

SELECT product_1, count(*) FROM products
group by product_1

Do you need count for  H, M, L ... for each field (product_1, product_2...) or only count(product_1), count(product_2)...?

Comment: Yes, I have separate columns per product.  And I need to count for H, M and L for each product.